# Mark inline equation to render as image with htlatex

Tags: equations, tex4ht, htlatex

Is there any way to mark some inline equation so it was rendered as pictures with `htlatex`? 
I know there is a way to make `htlatex` to render **all** inline equations as pictures, but i have many simple inline equations and i do not want so `htlatex` created picture for every easy equation. I want it rendered pictures for inline equations which i choose and somehow mark in source.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use some custom command, which will be redefined in the custom config file used by `tex4ht` to output the picture:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\picmath[1]{\ensuremath{#1}}
\begin{document}
\picmath{a=\frac{b}{c}}
\end{document}
```

and custom config file, `hello.cfg`:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}
\let\oldpicmath=\picmath
\renewcommand\picmath[1]{\Picture+{}\oldpicmath{#1}\EndPicture}
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

`\picmath` command is saved as `\oldpicmath` and then redefined to output its contents as picture with `\Picture+{} ... \EndPicture`. For equations which you don't want to convert to image, just use `$ ... $` as usual.

Compile your file with

```
 htlatex inputfile hello
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, exactly what i need. But i faced the problem: png-equations made with `\picmath{}` are not aligned by center of the string, the `align="middle"` is missing in html output. Any ideas on how to add `align="middle"` to `<img>` tag?

Comment: @Derp yes, it is known problem, see https://github.com/michal-h21/mathdimen for some discussion